Errors in 'prismarine-proxy' when connecting
I've been trying to make a Minecraft server proxy for Hypixel, a minigames server. The code is as following:
const { InstantConnectProxy } = require('prismarine-proxy')

const proxy = new InstantConnectProxy({
  loginHandler: (client) => { // client object has a username object, so you can store usernames with their respective logins
    return { username: "D3P_", auth: "microsoft",  } // the login the proxy will connect to the server with
  },
  serverOptions: { // options for the local server shown to the vanilla client
    version: '1.8.9',
    port: 25565,
  },
  clientOptions: { // options for the client that will connect to the proxied server
    version: '1.8.9',
    host: 'mc.hypixel.net' // server the proxy will connect to
  }
})

proxy.on('incoming', (data, meta, toClient, toServer) => { // packets incoming from the server to the client
  if (meta.name === 'world_particles') return // for 1.8.9, world_particles is the packet that contains particles, so by returning here, the client connected to the proxy won't get any particles
  toClient.write(meta.name, data) // otherwise send the packet to the client
})

proxy.on('outgoing', (data, meta, toClient, toServer) => { // packets outgoing from the client to the server
  if (meta.name === 'chat') console.log(data.message) // for 1.8.9, chat is the packet that the client sends to send a chat message to the server, so by using console.log, we can sniff the message before it hits the server, and even return early so it wouldn't hit the server
  toServer.write(meta.name, data) // otherwise send the packet to the client
})

I get these errors while connecting, and it never goes through
Disconnected
java.net.ConnectionException: Connection refused: no further information
Internal Exception: io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: java.io.IOException: Bad packet id 1280

Sometimes, I get random errors about out of bounds stuff. I don't know why it doesn't work. If this is unfixable, it would be appreciated if you could tell me an alternative that works :)
Also, I use Lunar Client 1.8.9.
Yes, my code is copied from the documentation. So, I expect it to work. The only changes I've made is using Microsoft for authentication, which should work, since it's an option.

Also, I just tried using vanilla 1.8.9, it still just errors

The issue is that the module "minecraft-packets" was updated from 1.5.0 to 1.5.7 with a breaking change. For a temporary fix you can either rename the versions "1.8" to "1.8.8" inside /node_modules/prismarine-proxy/src/instant_connect_proxy.js or alternatively downgrade minecraft-packets to 1.5.0.
Another issue will occur because the encryption fails, the only workaround I have found so far is disabling "online-mode" in /node_modules/prismarine-proxy/src/instant_connect_proxy.js (this is the authentication between your game and the proxy). Beware, this is a security risk if ran on an exposed network/server since anyone can now connect to your proxy.
source and more info:
https://github.com/PrismarineJS/prismarine-proxy/issues/42
https://github.com/PrismarineJS/prismarine-proxy/issues/40
